# Having many separate - unrleated datasets in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I'm using iReport 2.0.4 to export some data to excel from a java application.

My problem is my subreports are grouping under the top level report but I want them to be discrete reports. Currently it looks like this

**Order**

   -Order Line 1

    **Receipts**

       -Receipt Line 1

       -Receipt Line 2

    **Invoices**

       -Invoice Line 1

       -Invoice Line 2

**Order**

   -Order Line 2

    **Receipts**

       -Receipt Line 1

       ........

I want it to be 3 separate reports in one spreadsheet. Like this

**Order**

    all Order lines

**Receipts**

    all Receipt lines

**Invoices**

    all Invoice lines

Currently I have the Orders as the master report and the Receipts and Invoices as subreports, dropped into the detail band Orders.

What is the best way to get this layout, if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- ***First way. Using [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html)***

You can fill and compile three separate reports and then use [**JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#JASPER_PRINT_LIST) parameter for building the single report using code like this:

```java
JasperReport ordersReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(srcOrdersReport);
JasperPrint jpOrdersReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ordersReport, ordersParamsMap, ordersDataSource);

JasperReport receiptsReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(srcReceiptsReport);
JasperPrint jpReceiptsReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(receiptsReport, receiptsParamsMap, receiptsDataSource);

JasperReport invoicesReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(srcInvoicesReport);
JasperPrint jpInvoicesReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(invoicesReport, invoicesParamsMap, invoicesDataSource);

List<JasperPrint> printList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();

printList.add(jpOrdersReport);
printList.add(receiptsReport);
printList.add(invoicesReport);

JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, printList);

exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
exporter.exportReport();
```

You can look at this [sample for your *JR* version - 2.0.4](http://jasperforge.org/svn/repos/jasperreports/tags/jr-2-0-4/jasperreports/demo/samples/batchexport/) for more details.

- ***Second way. Using several datasets and list components***

You can add several datasets in *iReport 4.x version* to the single report. Every dataset may contain its own query. The ***list*** component can use its own dataset.

In this sample (build with *iReport 4.5.1*) I've placed 3 ***list*** components to the *Title* band:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="several_queries" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <subDataset name="OrdersDataset">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT TOP 5 ORDERID AS orderId, SHIPNAME AS orderShipName, SHIPCOUNTRY AS orderShipCounty, SHIPCITY  AS orderShipCity
FROM orders]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="ORDERID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="ORDERSHIPNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="ORDERSHIPCOUNTY" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="ORDERSHIPCITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="ReceiptsDataset">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT TOP 10 ID AS receiptId, CITY AS receiptCity FROM receipts]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="RECEIPTID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="RECEIPTCITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="InvoicesDataset">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT TOP 7 ID AS invoiceId, TOTAL AS invoiceSum FROM invoices]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="INVOICEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="INVOICESUM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="dataset1"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT 1 as t FROM dual WHERE 1=2]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="t" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="243" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="44" width="555" height="19"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="OrdersDataset">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="19" width="555">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="19"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="19"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERSHIPNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="19"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERSHIPCOUNTY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="19"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERSHIPCITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="130" width="400" height="18"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ReceiptsDataset">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="18" width="400">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="18"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RECEIPTCITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="18"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RECEIPTID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="4" width="400" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Orders]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer country]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer city]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="109" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="100" y="109" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[City]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="89" width="200" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Receipts]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="201" width="400" height="18"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="InvoicesDataset">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="18" width="400">
                        <textField pattern="###0.00;-###0.00">
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="18"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVOICESUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="18"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVOICEID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="161" width="200" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoices]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="100" y="181" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sum]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="181" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The report's design is:

[image: The report's design in iReport]

The result will be (via *iReport* preview):

[image: The report's result]

Comment: I used the adding the 3 reports to the list, then into the exporter method. Worked well.
Thanks for that.

Comment: In the snippet for the first way you define:
List<JasperPrint> printList = ...;
and then you use jprintlist, which is not defined:
jprintlist.add(jpOrdersReport);

Answer (score 0):

In [JasperReports 6.1.1 API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html) the `JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST` and `JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM` is **Deprecated** I add to @Alex K answer the current non deprecated metod:

**"First way. Using JasperReports API"**

replace (deprecated code):

```
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, printList);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
```

with

```
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(printList));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(output));
```